Not able to create websocket connection to istio
I have app running on behind istio gateway and proxy running as sidecar, when i make the connection request from chrome websocket client or wscat or python websocket-client and my requests reaches the app server and connection is upgraded.
but when i initiate the connection from my code using java jetty websocket client my requests never reach the sever, there are no access logs in the istio gateway as well.
Any idea why this strange behaviour ?

Does Chrome have a proxy set?

No. there are no proxies in place.

figured the fix, it was due to the older version of jetty websocket-client.
